# Aggregating quantities across multiple columns without a cursor or temporary table

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

If I have a table with two columns, A and B, and would like to count how many times an item shows up in both columns, is there a way to do so without using a cursor or temp table?

```
Ex:
Column A   Column B
BMW           Ford
Jaguar        BMW
Mercedes      Lexus
Chevrolet     Jaguar
BMW           Ford
```

I would like the result to be:

```
BMW        3
Jaguar     2
Mercedes   1
Chevrolet  1
Ford       2
Lexus      1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ColumnA, COUNT(*) as Times
FROM (
  SELECT ColumnA FROM ATable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ColumnB FROM ATable) Joined
GROUP BY ColumnA
```

Most DBMS require you to alias the derived table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x, COUNT(*)
   FROM (SELECT ColumnA AS x FROM t
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ColumnB FROM t)
  GROUP BY x
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say DBMS. If SQL Server you can use `UNPIVOT` to avoid scanning the table twice.

```
SELECT car, COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
UNPIVOT (car FOR col in (ColumnA, ColumnB)) u 
GROUP BY car
```

Depending on what indexes you have this could be either more or less efficient than the `UNION ALL` approach (If both `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` were indexed the `UNION ALL` query plan could do a merge join on the 2 indexes and feed that into the aggregation operator avoiding the need to sort the data that the `UNPIVOT` plan would require)